# Importing JS component into React App.tsx

Tags: reactjs, three.js

very new to React and trying to hack something together, which I'm struggling with.

I have a existing React (Typescript) app.  I am trying to add a Three.js 3D cube component to the page.
The threejs component is in a javascript file called ThreeScene.js and looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";

class myBox extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            this.mount.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
            var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x7e31eb });
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(cube);

            const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1);
            scene.add(light);
            camera.position.z = 2;

            var animate = function() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.z += 0.01;
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };
            animate();

            renderer.render(scene, camera);


        }
        render() {
            return ( <
                div ref = { ref => (this.mount = ref) }
                />
            )
        }
    }
    
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")
    ReactDOM.render( < myBox / > , rootElement);

export default myBox;
```

How would I then import that into my `App.tsx` and run it in my page?

Comment: import myBox from './hreeScene.js'

Comment: I got it working, the problem was my class name myBox started with a lowercase, changing to MyBox made typescript happy.